OIDC with PKCE : possible to put token in httpOnly cookie?
I have a front end Angular SPA application with some business spring boot backend APIs
The authentication process (OIDC PKCE) is managed by Angular and angular-oauth2-oidc npm library. Basically it means the client Angular app receives the token from authorization server.
I've heard storing id_token in localStorage (sessionStorage too) is a bad idea because of XSS vulnerabilities.
I know it's possible to put token in httpOnly, secure cookie when the authentication process is done by the backend (basically the backend receives the token from Authorization server and creates the secured cookie).
But when th authentication process is done by a public client SPA like Angular, is it possible to use secured cookies to transfer token to the back-end ?

Javascript in a browser cannot access HttpOnly cookies. That is the point of HttpOnly cookies. So yes you need to make a trade-off. Generally my feeling is that if XSS is possible, you're already so screwed protecting that token isn't going to make a bad situation much better, because even without that token the attacker can mostly do anything a user could do.

The SPA cannot issue HttpOnly cookies on its own and you would need to use a Backend for Frontend. This is considered a best practice, but adds complexity.
BENEFITS

The impact of XSS exploits is reduced. Eg when a user navigates away from a page the attacks end whereas a more concerted attack may be possible if tokens are exfiltrated.

Stakeholder perception is likely to be that the app is more secure. Many security reviewers may be aware of Dr Philippe De Ryck's recommendations in the above document.


IMPLEMENTATION
A secure cookie layer can be added to a JavaScript app in a few different ways. Eg it is possible to issue cookies using utility deployed APIs, so that introducing cookies has minimal impact on your Angular app's development and deployment:

Angular app runs at https://www.example.com
Cookies are issued at https://bff.example.com

LEAST PRIVILEGE
When using a BFF, the cookie transports an access token to APIs. Personally I like to keep the privileges and lifetime of the cookie header sent to APIs identical to those of the underlying access token. This minimizes the impact of another type of exploit: intercepted API requests and stolen cookie headers.

Thanks BFF pattern sounds good but would prefer using it as the last resort because it would require some important refactoring.
I was thinking about this pattern :
SPA is in charge of doing all the authentification process (the client remains SPA Angular). As soon as the SPA public client gets back the token from authorization server /token endpoint, it doesn't store it inside localStorage but sends it directly to my backend. My Spring boot backend then verifies the token and sends back a httpOnly cookie with token inside it. How good is this approach ?

Well the tokens are still revealed to the browser, though exposed less. A better option would be for a reverse proxy, eg NGINX, to receive the token endpoint response (if you could put one in front of the AS) and call your Spring Boot backend.

Why is it better to use something non standard like the BFF pattern, than a standard one like PKCE. Implementations for private clients are usually much more sloppy, for example using offline tokens or multiple use refresh tokens.
